# Number input for Vaadin 8

Tags: java, responsive-design, vaadin8

I need an Number input in vaadin what shows up a number input instead of the normal keyboard.

#### i have this

[image: android keyboard]

#### and i want this

[image: android number input]

Could only find html5-Widget but this is only supported by vaadin 7.

Has anybody some suggestions for me.

Thank you

Comment: i hope i made it more clearly now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use viritin `DoubleField` or `IntegerField` if `type='number'` is enough. 
If you want `type='tel'` instead you will need to use the extension `HtmlElementPropertySetter` from viritin, like

```
HtmlElementPropertySetter ext = new HtmlElementPropertySetter(component);
ext.setProperty("type", "tel");
```

https://github.com/viritin/viritin